# Matlab fitlm function gives a different RMSE respect the one calculated by hand

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I'm doing a WLS estimation and actually the RMSE (Root mean square error) given by the "fitlm" function is different by the one calculated by hand.

Here there is the MATLAB code

```
%% Generating data
x=unifrnd(0,30,100,1);
y=sin(x).*x;

wi=x; % weights
m_hat=fitlm(x,y,'Weights',wi); % the model
b_hat = m_hat.Coefficients.Estimate; % coefficients
y_hat = b_hat(1)+b_hat(2)*x; % model estimation

% RMSE extracted
rmse=m_hat.RMSE; % rmse "extracted" from fitlm

% RMSE by hand
RMSE_with_formula=sqrt(sum((y-y_hat).^2)/m_hat.DFE))
```

Can somebody explain why? Which is the correct one? Thanks.

Comment: Where in the "hand" calculation do you include the weights?

Comment: i didn't calculated it with weights. Should i ? If yes, can you show me how the formula changes? My professor explained that only IC for coefficients changes on WLS respect on OLS or on a normal regression model.

Comment: An unweighted RMSE hardly makes sense: it would be inconsistent with the purpose of the weights.  Indeed, one wonders whether *any* RMSE would make sense in general: how would you interpret it?

Comment: yes, the RMSE has a general sense. But an unweighted RMSE in WLS model doesn't have sense. Where should i put the weights in the by "hand" formula?

Comment: If in your code you do not divide by m_hat.DFE, do the results match?